# How to place <Text> on TOP of <Text> in React Native?

Tags: react-native

Im having trouble working out how to place a `<Text>` component ON TOP OF another `<Text>` component.

I tried zIndex but isn't making any change to layout. The "More..." text component is still rendering after the main `<Text>` area.

Appreciate some assistance, I'd like to have the "More..." Text item, render *ON TOP OF* the last word ("elite").

```

```
<View style={{paddingTop: 50, margin: 20}}>
  <Text
    style={{
    zIndex: 100,
   }}>
     <Text
       style={{
           zIndex: 104,
           backgroundColor: "green",
       }}>
           More...
     </Text>
  </Text>
</View>
```

```
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using *position: "absolute"* in the styles for the second Text component, then play around with sizing and left/top positioning to get it where you want.